# Not able to open a map in Windows Phone browser?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am not able to open the bingmap url below in my windows phone.It says "No results for this country or region.change your regional settings andtry again.".This Windows phone region belongs to india.

http://maps.live.com/default.aspx?cp=37.814692~-122.477339&style=o&lvl=1&tilt=-90&dir=0&alt=-1000&scene=1140291

It does open in my other windows phone where the region of my live account is USA.

Any clue how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot fix this as it's a region restriction for the account. The only thing you can do is to change your phone account region.